# Get the last route in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Well, made things simple, i currently develop with Symfony 3 and i meet a small problem when it comes to routing, i've made a back-office in order to manage article, forums and more, so, to do things simple like delete, update and lock articles, subject and more, i've made route, one for deleting, one for updating and one for locking the article.

But, here the problem, i've create a service that control every CRUD action and this one is call by my controller (in order to make my controller lighter), for exemple, if i want to delete a article, i call the service :

```
    $this->get('core.back')->deleteArticle($id);
    $this->addFlash('success', "L'article a été supprimé");
    return $this->redirectToRoute('equipe_admin');
```

My problem is simple, if i have multiple Blogs, i need to create a action by blog in order to delete the entities passed by the repository, but what i want, is take the route from where i come and make a if/elseif/else statement that say :

"If you comme from this road => delete the article => return to the last road"

After this, my controller can have only one action for deleting and i just use the if/else statement in order to make the redirection.

Well, if someone have meet the same problem or have a road to check in order to find the answer, i thanks you by advance.

Comment: If you want to know from which page user came, you can use HTTP_REFERER `$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');`

Comment: Thanks for the help Alok, i appreciate :)

Last question and i promise to never ask stupid question again, when i've grab the page from where user came with your solution, can i redirect to this route directly or should i need to call transform this road with a method ? 

Because, the header grab the page and not a route from the router ?

Comment: Yeah you can redirect to this route directly or you can also convert that URL into route by using router service. `$router = $this->get('router');$route = $router->match('/foo');`

Comment: Ok, so if i understand your solution, that's might look like this :     $this->get('core.back')->lockArticle($id);
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        $router = $this->get('router');
        $route = $router->match($referer);
        return $this->redirectToRoute($route);

Comment: Yeah, but $referer will have http://DOMAIN_NAME with it, you might have to play around with that as $router->match() will only accept router with out http://DOMAIN_NAME.

Comment: In Drupal, you can do: `return $this->redirect(Url::fromUserInput(parse_url(\Drupal::request()->headers->get('referer'))['path'])->getRouteName());`